# css scroll-snap not working when rule is first removed then added again (chrome)

Tags: css, scroll-snap-points

i have a container with `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;` and child elements with `scroll-snap-align: start;`. In chrome the scroll snapping works as expected.
i then remove the css rule regarding the scroll-snap-type via js and set it later back.
after that the snapping does not work.
is this a bug? am i doing something wrong? is this behaviour acording to the spec? or is there a workaround for it?

(i have only tested it in chrome browser on a windows machine.)

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/gjcs3y6k/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also remove and then add a rule for child elements, `scroll-snap-align`, it works ok.

I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gjcs3y6k/4/